# В 1С Объект.Наименование и Объект.Код откуда берутся?

Tags: 1с

Есть такой код:

```
Выбрать 
Значение, Объект.Наименование КАК Наименование, Объект.Код КАК Код 
Из РегистрСведений.ДополнительныеСведения
ГДЕ Значение В (&Значение)
```

Объект.Наименование и Объект.Код откуда берутся? Где их найти?

Answer (score 0):

`Значение, Объект` - это реквизиты у `РегистрСведений.ДополнительныеСведения`

Comment: Понятно. У реквизита `Объект` есть подразделы: `Наименование` и `Код`, их где смотреть?

Comment: @ВадимЧиркунов нажмите галочку "технического специалиста"

Comment: в 'РегистрСведений.ДополнительныеСведения' в конфигураторе стать на Объект и определить Тип, (Справочник.ХХХ) затем открыть ветку конфигурации стать на Справочник.ХХХ свойства (будут показаны реквизиты справочника) Наименование, Код - стандартные реквизиты (должны быть в списке)

Comment: @santavital
Можно более подробнее? У меня что-то такого нет. В типе просто справочник, без конкретного реквизита (т.е. в дереве справочника не указан галочкой конкретный реквизит). У меня версия 1С 8.3

Comment: в конфигураторе ставим курсор на нужный справочник, правый клик - Свойства, в палитре свойств "Длина кода", "Длина наименования"

Comment: второй вариант, в конфигураторе ставим курсор на нужный справочник, двойной клик левой, закладка "Данные"

Comment: @santavital там их нет к сожалению. Просто `Объект` показывается, без его структуры. Мне нужна структура `Объект`а. По подсказкам знаю что там есть `Наименование` и `Код`, но так и не понял где их посмотреть